# Adding dependant elements to blog that isn't created yet - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've said asp.net in the title as that is the technology I'm using, but it's probably a more general, 'best practices' kinda question.

I've got a "Create Blog" page and I'd like to allow the user to add images all on the first page - however, there is no BlogID since it hasn't actually been created yet.  What is the best way to add imageIDs when there is no parentID to relate it to?

I've been looking at a few methods, such as adding the images to a `static DataTable`, and then looping through that and adding the imageIDs after the blog has been created.  I've also thought about storing the imageIDs in a session and looping through that. 
Also I've thought about adding them into a pending table in the database with a Guid as the identifier and then processing these after the blog is created.  None of these ways seem particularly clean to me though - is there a better way that I'm not thinking of?

Thanks

Comment: use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() if you are using SQL Server and you'll get the item id

Comment: Thanks adrian - I'm actually fine with that part of it. The part I was wondering was about the best way to temporarily save the imageIDs until I could get the Scope Identity.  Really just thought there may have been a standard way of doing it that was different than the three ways above.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard. I remember I had such task me too and I used Session. I stored there the uploaded images and when the insert was finished, I just deleted the Session.